# Asp.net 3.5 still uses 2.0 compiler, so we just drop 3.5 dll's and it works?

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql

Is it true that asp.net 3.5 still uses the 2.0 compiler, and because of this, we can use 3.5 features on a server that only supports asp.net 2.0 as long as we drop the required .dll's into /bin?

In my case I need to use linqtosql on a server that only supports asp.net 2.0. (Client's decision, can't change this).

Answer (score 1):

In principal, you can, although you won't be able to use the new language features (the `var` keyword, extension methods, etc) in the ASPX and code-behind files. (These require the C# 3.0 compiler)